# How to select only one item from forEach loop and deselect others?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change element color onclick this element and onclick another element change color only that element

```
const postCategories = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cats-li');
const postCategoriesIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cat-img');
const postCats = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cats');

postCategories.forEach(function(categories,index){
    categories.addEventListener('click',function(){
        postCategoriesIcon[index].style.filter = "grayscale(0%)";
    });
});
```

[image: like in this image]

[image: like in this image]

Comment: usualy you will have to add a select class to the button then remove the select when the button is unselect. Do you want an example?

Comment: I need exactly that what is shown on images

Comment: select one change color for that one select another change color for that one and change other elements color to default

Comment: Please post your html it will  be faster to give you an example

Comment: Generally you have two options. Keep a reference in memory to the currently selected item, and on click, remove that selection and then select the new one. Option two, remove selection class from ALL of them on click, and then add selection class to the clicked item.

Answer (score 2):

untested... this keeps a references to the selected elements style and its default value before changing anything

```
const postCategories = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cats-li')
const postCategoriesIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cat-img')
const postCats = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cats')
let selected // [styleMap, "default filter value"]

postCategories.forEach(function (categories, index) {
  categories.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (selected) {
      // reset filter if any is selected
      selected[0].filter = selected[1] 
    }
    // store the selected style and (default) filter before changing
    selected = postCategoriesIcon[index].style
    selected = [selected, selected.filter]
    // set style
    selected[0].filter = "grayscale(0%)"
  })
})
```

Normally you would have a `selected` class and style it with css and do something in lines of:

```
const postCategories = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cats-li')
const postCategoriesIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cat-img')
const postCats = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cats')

postCategories.forEach(function (categories, index) {
  categories.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // remove the `selected` class from anywhere first
    postCategories.querySelectorAll('.selected').forEach(function (selected) {
      selected.classList.remove('selected')
    })
    // set the current element as selected
    postCategoriesIcon[index].classList.add('selected')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to do this )

```
const postCategories = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cats-li');
const postCategoriesIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cat-img');
const postCats = document.querySelectorAll('.post-cats');

postCategories.forEach(function(categories,index){
    categories.addEventListener('click',function(){

        const postCatsLength = postCats.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < postCatsLength; i++) {
            if (!postCategoriesIcon[i].classList.contains('post-cat-img-select') && !postCats[i].classList.contains('post-cats-selected')) {
                postCategoriesIcon[index].classList.add('post-cat-img-selected');
                postCats[index].classList.add('post-cats-selected');
            }else{
                for(let i = 0; i < postCatsLength; i++){
                    postCategoriesIcon[i].classList.remove('post-cat-img-selected');
                    postCats[i].classList.remove('post-cats-selected');
                }
                postCategoriesIcon[index].classList.remove('post-cat-img-selected');
                postCats[index].classList.remove('post-cats-selected');
            }
        }


    });
});
```